# System.Net.Http.HttpClient Disable Caching (.Net Standart Project)

Tags: c#, httpclient, http-caching

In my .NET Standard project I'm using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. How can I disable all caching (request caching especially) in `HttpClient`?

If server sends responses with no cache header problem solves. But I want to make this on client side. I want to completely disable all caching.

Thanks.

Edit: It looks like I could use `WebRequestHandler` but this does not exist in .NET standard. I can only use `HttpClientHandler` but `HttpClientHandler` doesn't have any option about caching.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use CacheControlHeaderValue in HttpClient

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
{
  NoCache = true
}
```

For more information you can look
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.cachecontrolheadervalue

Answer (score 4):

I tried everything, this one worked for me. Just in case some is not able to make the accepted answer work:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/v?time=" + DateTime.Now);
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```